# Exceeded Maximum Execution Time for Google Scripts while consolidating GSheet Data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a parent volunteer at a local arts high school in southern California. I watched a YouTube video to write a script to help consolidate individual student data into a single Google Sheet. It worked wonderfully for the past year, however, I am now receiving an "Exceeded maximum execution time" error.

How can I solve this issue? The current script is below.

```
function combineDataToMaster(){
    var folder        = DriveApp.getFolderById( "addfolderID123456789123456789" );
    var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
    var file;
    var fileType;
    var ssID;
    var combinedData = [];
    var data;

    while( filesIterator.hasNext() ) { 
        file     = filesIterator.next();
        fileType = file.getMimeType();

        if( fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ) {
            ssID = file.getId();
            data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
            data = data.map( function( r ){ return r.concat( [ file.getName() ] ); } );
            data = data.map( function( r ){ return r.concat( file.getId()       ); } );

            combinedData = combinedData.concat( data );
        } //if ends here
    }//whileloop ends here

    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName( "Consolidated Sheets" );

    ws.getRange( "A2:L" ).clearContent();
    ws.getRange( 2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[ 0 ].length ).setValues( combinedData );
}

function getLastRowSpecial( range ){
    var rowNum = 0;
    var blank  = false;

    for( var row = 0; row < range.length; row++ ) {
        if( range[ row ][ 0 ] === "" && !blank ){
            rowNum = row;
            blank = true;
        } else if( range[ row ][ 0 ] !== "" ) {
            blank = false;
        };
    };

    return rowNum;
};

function getDataFromSpreadsheet( ssID ){
    var ss            = SpreadsheetApp.openById( ssID );
    var ws            = ss.getSheetByName( "Point Entry Form" );
    var columnToCheck = ws.getRange( "A5:A" ).getValues();
    var lastrow       = getLastRowSpecial( columnToCheck );
    var dataRange     = ws.getRange( 6, 1, lastrow, ws.getLastColumn() );
    var data          = dataRange.getValues();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: In your situation, how many files are in the folder?

Comment: 150 to 200 student GSheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script has a limit of its execution time([6 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)).
I encountered the same issue, and I've created a helpful class to solve this problem.

Go to [this repository](https://github.com/inclu-cat/LongRun/blob/main/generated-gs/LongRun.gs) and get LongRun.gs and put it into your project (Copy and paste the contents of the file).
Then modify your combineDataToMaster() as follows. (I wrote comments starting with [inclu-cat] where I modified it)

```js
function combineDataToMaster(){
    var folder        = DriveApp.getFolderById( "addfolderID123456789123456789" );
    var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
    var file;
    var fileType;
    var ssID;
    var combinedData = [];
    var data;

    // [inclu-cat] if you want to forcibly suspend the process to see what will happen, uncomment this.
    // LongRun.instance.setMaxExecutionSeconds(1);

    // [inclu-cat] get the index to resume(zero for the first time)
    // [inclu-cat] if it is first time, clear range first. otherwise find the row where to start pasting.
    let startIndex = LongRun.instance.startOrResume('combineDataToMaster');
    let index = 0;
    let pasteRow;
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName( "Consolidated Sheets" );
    if ( startIndex == 0 ){
      ws.getRange( "A2:L" ).clearContent();
      pasteRow = 2;
    } 
    else {
      pasteRow = ws.getLastRow() + 1;
    }   

    while( filesIterator.hasNext() ) { 
        file     = filesIterator.next();

        // [inclu-cat] skip until index == startIndex
        if (index < startIndex){
          index++;
          continue;
        }

        // [inclu-cat] Each time before executing a process, you need to check if it should be stopped or not.
        if (LongRun.instance.checkShouldSuspend('combineDataToMaster', index)) {
          // if checkShouldSuspend() returns true, the next trigger has been set
          // and you should get out of the loop.
          console.log('*** The process has been suspended. ***');
          break;
        }

        fileType = file.getMimeType();

        if( fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ) {
            ssID = file.getId();
            data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
            data = data.map( function( r ){ return r.concat( [ file.getName() ] ); } );
            data = data.map( function( r ){ return r.concat( file.getId()       ); } );

            // [inclu-cat] Paste the data every time
            // combinedData = combinedData.concat( data );
            ws.getRange( pasteRow, 1, data.length, data[ 0 ].length ).setValues( data );
            pasteRow += data.length;
        } //if ends here

        // [inclu-cat] increment counter
        index++;

    }//whileloop ends here

    // [inclu-cat] you must always call end() to reset the long-running variables if there is no next trigger.
    LongRun.instance.end('combineDataToMaster');

    // [inclu-cat] these lines are moved
    // var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName( "Consolidated Sheets" );
    // ws.getRange( "A2:L" ).clearContent();
    // ws.getRange( 2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[ 0 ].length ).setValues( combinedData );

}
```

An explanation of the LongRun class can be found in [this blog](https://inclucat.wordpress.com/2021/10/24/an-easy-way-to-deal-with-google-apps-scripts-6-minute-limit/).

Comment: Hi - Thank you so much! I appreciate the effort, however, upon testing the solution provided, the process suspends (as expected) and no more data is collected. The final consolidation is missing 1k+ records. Is there a way to have the script start again from where it left off so there is no data loss? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for testing. How many sheets are missing?  
If you are using Apps Script Editor, could you check the Execution panel(like [this](https://imgur.com/2TOxz3S)) and whether there are any errors?

Comment: Hi - I checked the execution panel and no errors. The time-driven execution process is not writing data to the combined data spreadsheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hmm... I ran it for a quick test and it worked, so I think there may be another problem. However, without providing some samples of your data, it's difficult to find the cause. If you'd like, you can chat with me on Reddit and I'll look into it a bit. My account is [this](https://www.reddit.com/user/inclu_cat). (because I think it might be better to avoid chatting in the comments section of StackOverflow.)